# Is there a pattern for propagating details of both errors and warnings?

Tags: python, design-patterns, error-handling, warnings

Is there a common pattern for propagating details of both errors and warnings? By *errors* I mean serious problems that should cause the flow of code to stop. By *warnings* I mean issues that merit informing the user of a problem, but are too trivial to stop program flow.

I currently use exceptions to deal with hard errors, and the Python logging framework to record warnings. But now I want to record warnings in a database field of the record currently being processed instead. I guess, I want the warnings to bubble up in the same manner as exceptions, but without stopping program flow.

```
>>> import logging
>>>
>>> def process_item(item):
...     if item:
...         if item == 'broken':
...             logging.warning('soft error, continue with next item')

...     else:
...         raise Exception('hard error, cannot continue')
...
>>> process_item('good')
>>> process_item(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in process_item
Exception: hard error, cannot continue
>>> process_item('broken')
WARNING:root:soft error, continue with next item
```

*This example (and my current problem) is in Python, but it should apply to other languages with exceptions too.*

---

Following [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56541/david)'s suggestion and a brief play with the example below, Python's `warnings` module is the way to go.

```
import warnings

class MyWarning(Warning):
    pass

def causes_warnings():
    print 'enter causes_warnings'
    warnings.warn("my warning", MyWarning)
    print 'leave causes_warnings'

def do_stuff():
    print 'enter do_stuff'
    causes_warnings()
    causes_warnings()
    causes_warnings()
    print 'leave do_stuff'

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    # Trigger a number of warnings.
    do_stuff()
    # Do something (not very) useful with the warnings generated
    print 'Warnings:',','.join([str(warning.message) for warning in w])
```

Output:

```
enter do_stuff
enter causes_warnings
leave causes_warnings
enter causes_warnings
leave causes_warnings
enter causes_warnings
leave causes_warnings
leave do_stuff
Warnings: my warning,my warning,my warning
```

Note: Python 2.6+ is required for `catch_warnings`.

Comment: FYI, it probably would have been better to post your solution as an answer, rather than editing it into the question... nice that you figured it out, though.

Comment: I'd have put my example as a comment to yours, but I can't do nice formatting in a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into Python's `warnings` module, http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html

I don't think there's much you can say about this problem without specifying the language, as non-terminal error handling varies greatly from one language to another.

Comment: +1: warnings module.  Icky to configure the first time (soooo many options) but once configured it rules.

Comment: Crossbreeding warnings and logging modules is not easy but it is possible with some work.

Answer (score -1):

Serious errors should bubble up, warning should just be logged in place without throwing exceptions.